# Add Custom Grid View to the different tabs of a Sliding Tab Layout

Tags: android, gridview, tabs, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have made the different tabs of a Sliding Tab Layout by referring to this tutorial - 
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

I want to add a Custom GridView to all the tabs of the Layout. I tried using an adapter but that does not work.
Kindly tell me a process or direct me to a tutorial.

swipe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.example.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Swipe.java

```
public class Swipe extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
ImageView img;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPageAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"M","N","A","G","W","D"};
    int Numboftabs =6;
    private static int pos;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    pos=intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pac);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(pos);


// Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

// Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
    }
});

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

  }
```

tab1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="You Are In Tab 2"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

There is a textview here. I don not want the text View but a Custom GridView.

tab1.java

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
    return v;
}
 }
```

Similarly for all other tabs.

Comment: Perhaps someone may be able to show you how it fits into your work if you had some code as part of your question.

Comment: I have added the code. I am using almost the same code as is there in the tutorial whose link I had specified in the question.